# What is best practise to migrate On-premises SQL Server to Azure VM - Dynamic SQL Agent Jobs in AlwaysOn offering

Tags: sql-server, azure, windows-server-2012

I am trying to migrate On-premises SQL Server to Azure VM. 
I am writing in reference to below link
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-migrate-onpremises-database/#azure-vm-deployment-wizard-tutorial

I am having multiple applications in which few are hosted in **Azure** and few are **On-premises.**
All these applications contact **on-premise SQL Server for data manipulations**.
In some scenario these applications **creates dynamic SQL Agent Jobs**!

Now my requirement is to move **on-premise SQL Server to Azure cloud**. I would like to know how can I manage **these dynamic SQL Agents in Azure?**

**In short, My question is**: how can I migrate below items?

1. SSIS packages associated with these databases
2. SQL Agent Jobs scheduled in server (created dynamically)
3. File Stream associated with server databases

Also I am planning to use **SQL Server "AlwaysOn" offering**.  So how to synch these SQL Agent Jobs in these shared Virtual Machines?

I was referring https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-general-limitations/ and it says as follow

> Microsoft Azure SQL Database does not support SQL Server Agent or
>   jobs. You can, however, run SQL Server Agent on your on-premises SQL
>   Server and connect to Microsoft Azure SQL Database.

SQL Agents can be dynamically created as shown here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3052/simple-way-to-create-a-sql-server-job-using-tsql/  My question is, will these stored procedures run in azure cloud?

**Update**
It’s challenge but can be done. We need to setup new Job, which constantly monitors and pull the current role of the replica, based on PRIMARY role, we run the job needs to do if it is the primary.

**Below link gives me hint**
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45137/sql-server-agent-jobs-and-availability-groups but I am looking for step by step blog/article to achieve this.